# Github API lists deleted gists

Tags: github, github-api, gist

When using the Github API with Gists, it lists gists that do not exist anymore:

```
require 'github_api'

github = Github.new do |config|
  config.oauth_token = 'mytoken'
end

gists = github.gists.list
```

returns 30 results, but I only have 6 gists in total (both private and public). The listed gists have existed at some point in the past, but they were delete since.

If I try to delete the gists returned by the list, I get an exception because the IDs do not exist anymore.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's strange. Can you try fetching the list of gists using curl? `curl -u "username" https://api.github.com/gists` and see if it gives the same result? I just tried creating and deleting a gist and it didn't show up in the API call after I deleted it.

Comment: Yes, I get the same result via the curl command.

Comment: If you are sure the gists that are showing up have been deleted - this sounds like something to be reported to GitHub support. I suggest you ping them on https://twitter.com/GitHubAPI and point them to this stack overflow page. Or just use the generic form https://github.com/contact. And let us know what you find out.

Comment: Any updates about this? Also which gem are you using? Octokit is their officially supported gem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with `curl`, and deleted gists are not in the list.

`curl -s -H "Authorization: token $github_oauth_token" 'https://api.github.com/gists?per_page=100'`